# Using Envira Gallery and ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, image-gallery

I don't know if someone is able to help me but I'm having trouble getting Envira Gallery to work with ACF pro.

What I'm trying to do is have Envira Gallery pick-up the gallery I've made with ACF. It should be possible for what I've read. And it kind of works at the moment. I've read [this](https://www.jowaltham.com/display-advanced-custom-fields-envira-gallery/) tutorial about a 1000 times to check if I've done anything wrong but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have made a gallery in Envira Gallery called `New fotos` and it got ID `7522` and I've also created an ACF gallery field called `get_my_fotos` and put some images in it, as instructed by the tutorial. I've grabbed the code from the github link in the comments since that was a newer code.

My HTML:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="container" style="min-height:300px;margin-top:90px;">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[envira-gallery id="7522"]'); ?>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And now the script to enable the Envira Gallery to work with  ACF:

```
/*
 * Populate Envira Gallery with ACF gallery field
 *
 * Filters the gallery $data and replaces with the image data for our images in the ACF gallery field.
 *
 * @uses ACF Pro
 * @uses Envira Gallery
 * @param $data
 * @param $gallery_id
 */
function envira_acf_gallery( $data, $gallery_id ) {

    // Target desired Envira gallery using ID
    if ( $data[ "id" ] == 7522 ) {

        //Setup new array to populate Envira gallery
        $newdata = array();

        // Don't lose the original gallery id and configuration
        $newdata[ "id" ] = $data[ "id" ];
        $newdata[ "config" ] = $data[ "config" ];

        if ( function_exists( 'get_field' ) )
        // Get array of images data from desired ACF gallery field
            $image_ids = get_field( 'get_my_fotos' );

        // Check to make sure array has images
        if( is_array( $image_ids ) ) {

            // Populate the Envira gallery with meta from the ACF gallery
            foreach( $image_ids as $image_id ) {
                $newdata[ "gallery" ][ ( $image_id["id"] ) ][ "status" ] = 'active';    
                $newdata[ "gallery" ][ ( $image_id["id"] ) ][ "src" ] = $image_id["url"];
                $newdata[ "gallery" ][ ( $image_id["id"] ) ][ "title" ] = $image_id["title"];
                $newdata[ "gallery" ][ ( $image_id["id"] ) ][ "link" ] = $image_id["url"];
                $newdata[ "gallery" ][ ( $image_id["id"] ) ][ "alt" ] = $image_id["alt"];
                $newdata[ "gallery" ][ ( $image_id["id"] ) ][ "thumb" ] = $image_id["sizes"]["thumbnail"];
            }
        }
        // Return the new array of images
        return $newdata;
    }

}
// Add new image data to the envira gallery
add_filter( 'envira_gallery_pre_data', 'envira_acf_gallery', 10, 2);
```

Now, if I check my inspector I see:

```
<div id="envira-gallery-wrap-7496" class="envira-gallery-wrap envira-gallery-theme-base envira-lightbox-theme-base_dark" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
</div>
```

Without the script I see the following:

```
<div id="envira-gallery-wrap-7522" class="envira-gallery-wrap envira-gallery-theme-base envira-lightbox-theme-base_dark" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
    </div>
```

So it's IS picking up some code, but it looks like its an older ID of an gallery I've deleted. But I can't seem to get why it's not picking up the ID i've given in the script. Thus showing no images.

Has anyone tried this before? I hope there is some help here. I've also tried the script in the tutorial itself but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue. Adding the following solved it:

```
add_filter( 'envira_gallery_get_transient_markup', '__return_false' );
```

See [How to Remove Fragment Cache from Envira](https://enviragallery.com/docs/how-to-remove-fragment-cache-from-envira/) for more info.

Comment: Hi, I'm using a very similar code but i found that the lightbox always opens on first image of galleries generated this way. any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way around this is to use the Dynamic Addon available with Envira Gallery. You can set this to automatically display the default WordPress gallery as an Envira gallery if a shortcode or the classic editor is used (does not work with the block editor). You can then use an ACF gallery field and output the data as a WordPress gallery and it is displayed as an Envira gallery.

Instructions for configuring the Envira gallery are on [Envira Dynamic Addon page](http://enviragallery.com/docs/dynamic-addon/)

Code taken from ACF Gallery docs to display the shortcode is:

```
// Load value (array of ids).
$image_ids = get_field('gallery');
if( $image_ids ) {

// Generate string of ids ("123,456,789").
$images_string = implode( ',', $image_ids );

// Generate and do shortcode.
// Note: The following string is split to simply prevent our own website from rendering the gallery shortcode.
$shortcode = sprintf( '[' . 'gallery ids="%s"]', esc_attr($images_string) );
echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
}
```

I've checked it out on a localhost site and works fine. Since it uses the shortcode it might be less susceptable to problems caused by Envira gallery code changing.